# Removing array brackets and quotes in print

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to print a couple different array objects at once (one random item per array, to be exact) and it's displaying strangely:

`["Not"]["*"]%`

Well, not strangely. I understand that's what the array objects look like, but my question is how can I print them *without* the brackets and quotes? Here's my code:

```
w = open('words.txt').read.split("\n").sample(1)

print w

s = Array["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "*", "+"].sample(1)
print s
```

Also, what's the deal with that `%` symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. The usage of `(1)` was causing the problem.